# Appengine Backend not triggered from cron

Tags: java, google-app-engine

Here's my configuration in backends.xml and cron.xml respectively:

```
 <backends>
<backend name="score">
    <class>B1</class>
    <instances>2</instances>
    <options>
        <dynamic>true</dynamic>
    </options>
</backend></backends>
```

and

```
<cronentries><cron>
    <url>/ProcessingEngine</url>
    <description>Get Posts</description>
    <schedule>every 45 minutes</schedule>
    <target>score</target>
</cron></cronentries>
```

I configured it this way so as to call the Backend job through cron.xml. But, for some reason, the Backend is not triggered and I don't see any logs that indicate Backend code has been executed. The Cron Tab in Admin section of AppEngine says the cron failed.

Note: I am able to run the Backend job via Admin console's Start button.

Comment: When you go to /ProcessingEngine directly does the backend handler get called?

Comment: I am able to access /ProcessingEngine though browser,but I think the appengine is still considering it as a regular cron job, because the logs are appearing in the application section and not in backends section of the admin console.

Comment: what if you explicitly address the backend, e.g. score.appname.appspot.com/ProcessingEngine

Comment: I get this error: Error: Server Error
The service you requested is not available yet.
Please try again in 30 seconds.

Comment: oh yeah, it's probably not set to be public so you can't directly test it like that.

Comment: Do you think, I have configured something wrong ?

Comment: no public is not the default. Your config looks ok to me but I only really know the python side of things. Just trying to see if you can get your task to execute on the backend at all, regardless of how it's triggered.

Comment: Currently, as noted in the question, I am able to trigger my backend through admin console, and it works fine.

Comment: Yeah, I saw that but TBH I don't know what you mean by that as that simply starts the backend up, it does not run any job on it or anything or mean it's accessible, etc. But as the cron job comes in on the same URL that's where I'd start to test.

Comment: Thanks @PaulC for your help, I have found the answer(written below)

Answer (score 0):

Turns out to be a silly mistake. The only thing you need to do is Start the backend instance in the Admin console and keep it that way. Shut it down only when necessary.

Comment: In python you can also set it to be "dynamic" so it starts up and shuts down automatically depending on the traffic. This can help save quota at the expense of some initial latency.

Comment: Yes, same is the case with Java.